# DynamoDB conditional write error : Value must be provided when Exists is true for Attribute:

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I am getting this error on trying to make an update in local dynamodb
'One or more parameter values were invalid: Value must be provided when Exists is true for Attribute: AssetLabel (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
[junit] com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Value must be provided when Exists is true for Attribute: AssetLabel (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)'

i can see the attribute assetLabel is present in the object. still the error says assetLabel is missing.

```
    @Test
    public void testExecuteBackfill() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Setup
        AssetRecord assetDetailsRecord = createAssetDetailsRecord(TestConstants.ASSET_LABEL_1, AssetStatusBO.ACTIVE);
        localDynamoMapper.save(assetDetailsRecord);

        // Assert Asset mapping unchanged
        AssetRecord fetchedAssetMappingRecord = loadAssetRecord(TestConstants.ASSET_LABEL_1, TestConstants.RANGE_KEY_LATEST);

        // Assert Asset detail changes
        AssetRecord fetchedAssetDetailsRecord = loadAssetRecord(TestConstants.ASSET_LABEL_1, TestConstants.RANGE_KEY_LATEST);
        System.out.println("fetchedAssetDetailsRecord = " +fetchedAssetDetailsRecord);
        //Mockito.when(assetDAO.getAssetByAssetLabel(TestConstants.ASSET_LABEL_1)).thenReturn(TestConstants.ASSET_BO);
        remarksAndMonitoringStatusBackfillerScriptHelper.executeBackfill(TEST_IOT_DATA_FILE_PATH);

        // Assert Asset detail changes
        fetchedAssetDetailsRecord = loadAssetRecord(TestConstants.ASSET_LABEL_1, TestConstants.RANGE_KEY_LATEST);
    }
```

code for creating table

```
    private void createTable() {
        final CreateTableRequest createTableRequest
                = localDynamoMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(AssetRecord.class);
        createTableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L));
        createTableRequest.getGlobalSecondaryIndexes().forEach(index -> {
            index.setProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType("ALL"));
            index.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L));
        });
        localDynamo.createTable(createTableRequest);
    }
```

Entity used to create table

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = AssetRecordConstants.TABLE_NAME)
public class AssetRecord {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = AssetRecordConstants.ASSET_LABEL)
    private String assetLabel;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = AssetRecordConstants.RANGE_KEY)
    private String rangeKey;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = AssetRecordConstants.NODE_ID)
    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexNames =
            {AssetRecordConstants.ASSET_TYPE_INDEX, AssetRecordConstants.MAPPED_RESOURCE_LABEL_INDEX})
    private String nodeId;

    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = AssetRecordConstants.ASSET_TYPE)
    @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = AssetRecordConstants.ASSET_TYPE_INDEX)
    private AssetTypeBO assetType;
}
```